# Simple docker-compose with two services: nginx and php

Tags: php, nginx, docker, gateway, docker-compose

I'm beginning with [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) and [nginx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx), and I'm trying to setup a two container environment running:

- `nginx:latest` on one side
- `php:fpm` on the other side

I'm having trouble with php-fpm: I always get a **502 Bad Gateway** error.

My setup is straightforward (`$TEST_DIR` is my working directory).

My Docker compose config `TEST_DIR/docker-compose.yml`:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
        - "8080:80"
    volumes:
        - ./www:/usr/share/nginx/html
        - ./conf/nginx.conf:/nginx.conf
        - ./logs/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    links:
        - php:php
    command: nginx -c /nginx.conf

php:
    image: php:fpm
    ports:
        - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
        - ./www:/var/www/html
```

The nginx config `$TEST_DIR/conf/nginx.conf`:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  2048;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

http {

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    server_tokens off;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log off;
    error_log off;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    open_file_cache max=100;


    upstream php-upstream {
        server php:9000;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        # Pass PHP scripts to PHP-FPM
        location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass    php-upstream;

            include         fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param   HTTPS off;
        }

        error_log  /var/log/nginx/php_error.log;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/php_access.log;
    }
}

daemon off;
```

Then, I put my PHP content in the same directory as my `docker-compose.yml`:

`$TEST_DIR/www/test.php`

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If I start the infrastructure using `docker-compose up` and then go to `localhost:8080/test.php`, then I get the **502 Bad Gateway**
and the following error from nginx:

```
[error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (113: No route to host) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.17.42.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /phpinsfo2.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.17.0.221:9000", host: "localhost:8080"
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: I don't know if it solves the problem but it seems that there is a typo in the definition of the volume for the php container `./www:/var/wwww/html`

Comment: I verified that fixing the typo in `./www:/var/wwww/html` allows me to see the content of the `/test.php` page. Although your error `connect() failed (113: No route to host)` might indicate an issue that I cannot reproduce. Are you using the latest version of both docker and docker-compose?

Comment: I'm using **docker 1.7.0 build 0baf609** and **docker-compose 1.3.1**.
Event with that typo fixed, i still have the same issues:
The nginx server serve correctly static file, but php file are not routed to php-fpm, i'm still getting the 502 Bad Gateway error  
The point is that i do not understand if request are routed to the php fpm or not ... How can i test that ?

Comment: Maybe an other usefull information: I'm running docker on fedora 21 with selinux disabled

Comment: Some more informations: From the nginx container, i'm able to ping the php container, and also i'm able to nmap the 9000 port of the php container. From what **nmap say, the 9000 port seams to be filtered instead of simply open**, can this be the cause of my troubles ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work.

The problem was that my host computer (Fedora 21) had a firewall enabled.

So doing: `systemctl stop firewalld` solved my problem.

Apparently this is a well known problem at Red Hat Linux:
[Bug 1098281 - Docker interferes with firewall initialisation via firewalld](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1098281)

Comment: I thought that docker was updating iptables as part of it's networking magic.  I guess there are a few kinks to be worked out still.  This helped me.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: Is disabling firewalld still required? As far as I know the bug was closed.